# Is there a document describing the Cycles BRDF implementation in detail?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

Where can I find a document describing the way Cycles BRDFs are implemented? 
I am looking for details on the Specular D, G, F and diffuse.

Comment: I think this is off topic but I'm not quite sure. Hopefully someone else has a better idea of if it is or not. Anyway, if you haven't already, you should go the BlenderArtists and ask that, or go to #blendercoders on irc, where you're much more likely to get your question answered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for resources for programming, not a question about Blender it's self.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Blender C/C++ source code.
These questions are considered outside the scope of this StackExchange as [defined in the help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Development questions should be asked of the developers directly instead, see the [contacting developers page of the blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact)